# django urlpattern for repeating group?

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

I am trying to do some category/subcategory routing in django(1.5).
I have 5 level for categories, which could look like.

```
url(r'^(?P<category>\w*)/$', SearchResults.as_view(), name='search_results'),
url(r'^(?P<category>\w*)/(?P<sublevel1>\w*)/$', SearchResults.as_view(), name='search_results'),
url(r'^(?P<category>\w*)/(?P<sublevel1>\w*)/(?P<sublevel2>\w*)/$', SearchResults.as_view(), name='search_results'),
url(r'^(?P<category>\w*)/(?P<sublevel1>\w*)/(?P<sublevel2>\w*)/(?P<sublevel3>\w*)/$', SearchResults.as_view(), name='search_results'),
url(r'^(?P<category>\w*)/(?P<sublevel1>\w*)/(?P<sublevel2>\w*)/(?P<sublevel3>\w*)/(?P<sublevel4>\w*)/$', SearchResults.as_view(), name='search_results'),
```

But I wonder if there is a better way to do it ?
Something with regex with a repeating pattern or alike.

thanks.

Comment: If you still want to keep the named groups, I don't think so.

Comment: Even numbers won't be kept. I believe that splitting by `/` would be easier instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex patterns, the number of groups is "fixed at compile time". You'll need to make a group that matches n-repetitions of your pattern and then split it after you've captured it.

You'll need to use something like `^(?P<categories>(?:[\w]+\/?)+)$`

Then in your view,

```
categories = filter(bool, categories.split('/'))
```